# How do i get the x axis to only show my data i want to plot? Instead of it including labels with no plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting dates vs integars. However because the date range is 100 days apart, matplotlib automatically includes every date between the 100 days, even when only 20 or so have data to plot. So my questions is, how do i get the x axis to only produce the dates that have data to plot? Also, at the moment the dates are squashed in a horizontal way, how do i get them in a vertical way so more can fit?

Here is a picture of my graph at the moment:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
    import datetime as dt
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates

    array1 = ['2014-10-28', '2014-11-17', '2014-09-29', '2014-10-17', '2014-10-22']
    array2 = [1,4,5,6,9]

    x = [dt.datetime.strptime(a,'%Y-%m-%d').date() for a in array1]    
    plt.plot_date((x), (array2), 'ro')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Or better yet, just an example piece of code that works. It's much harder for people to help you if they have to fill in the blanks.

Comment: ... and sendArray is?

Comment: I have hardcoded the example. Sorry about that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so first, you can jsut use the `fig.autofmt_xdate()` function to deal with the xtick labels automatically - that's the easiest way.

So you'll have something like this:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib import pyplot
from random import randint


array1 = ['2014-10-28', '2014-11-17', '2014-09-29', '2014-10-17', '2014-10-22']
array2 = [1,4,5,6,9]


dates = ["2014-{month:0>2d}-{day:0>2d}".format(month=m, day=d) for m in [1,5] for d in range(1,32)]
dates = [dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d').date() for d in dates]
freqs = [randint(0,4) for _ in dates]

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot_date(dates, freqs, "ro")

fig.autofmt_xdate()

pyplot.show()
```

[image]

which still has the large gap you don't want, but the tick labels are better.

Next, to deal with the split, there are a few options, but they're not in the main matplotlib yet (that i know of). It's done by actually drawing two plots, removing the spines in the middle, and using the `sharey` option:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib import pyplot
from random import randint
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator


dates = ["2014-{month:0>2d}-{day:0>2d}".format(month=m, day=d) for m in [1,5] for d in range(1,10)]
dates = [dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d').date() for d in dates]
freqs = [randint(0,4) for _ in dates]



fig = pyplot.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2, sharey=ax1)

ax1.plot_date(dates, freqs, "ro")
ax2.plot_date(dates, freqs, "ro")


#set the upper and lower bounds for the two adjacent plots
ax1.set_xlim(xmax=dt.datetime.strptime("2014-01-11", '%Y-%m-%d').date())
ax2.set_xlim(xmin=dt.datetime.strptime("2014-05-01", '%Y-%m-%d').date())


for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
  _ = ax.get_xticklabels() #For some reason, if i don't do this, then it only prints years for the tick labels. :/
  ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator(maxticks=6))

#Turn off the spines in the middle
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

ax1.yaxis.tick_left()

ax2.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

pyplot.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1)

fig.autofmt_xdate()

pyplot.show()
```

There are still a few extra things which need cleaning up, but i imagine you get the point.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate the xtick labels with:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

and plot the dates *evenly* along the x-axis by using:

```
x = np.arange(n)
ax.plot(x, array2, 'ro')
```

and then relabeling the xticks:

```
locs = x
labels = [d.strftime('%b %d') for d in dates]
plt.xticks(locs, labels)
```

Note however that a side-effect of setting the locs and labels manually is that
the ticks will no longer automatically adapt to changes of scale as they normally would when you use the GUI translate or zoom tools.

---

```
import time
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n, m = 20, 30
now = dt.date.today()
dates = [now+dt.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(n//2)+range(m,m+n//2)]
x = np.arange(n)
array2 = np.random.random(n)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, array2, 'ro')

locs = x
labels = [d.strftime('%b %d') for d in dates]
plt.xticks(locs, labels)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the main part of it is still unanswered. The middle section of the graph is emtpy. and many other dates have no plots. I want the x axis to only show the dates that im plotting?

Comment: In a way, yes. But lets say i have 10 dates that have plots associated to them. But the date range between them dates is 100 days. Instead of plotting the 100 days, is there a way i can only plot the 10 dates evenly on the x axis? Thanks for your answer. Been more than enough help :)

Comment: @jamesjames94 yes there is. I'm writing it up now.